# Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException: Element 'argument': Duplicate key-sequence

Tags: magento2, exception, debugging, debug, product-detail-page

I have an error when the developer-mode is active.
The Exception is thrown out when entering any product detail page.
I am running Magento 2.3.4.

could you please help in finding a solution

```
1 exception(s):
```

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': Duplicate key-sequence ['title'] in key identity-constraint 'blockArgumentName'.
Line: 1388

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'argument': Duplicate key-sequence ['title'] in key identity-constraint 'blockArgumentName'.
Line: 1388

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:512]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:488]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:206]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:257]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:882]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:215]
#15 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php:47]
#16 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#27 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#29 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is all already written.
Somewhere in your layout configuration there are 2 *.xml file in the same scope

> name  Name that can be used to address the block to which this attribute is assigned. The name must be unique per generated page. If not specified, an automatic name will be assigned in the format ANONYMOUS_n

You have to find where. The tip is a `['title']` => name='title'
We can't do this for you...